# How can I use join and sum with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to select most voted articles on my website. Right now, I have this feature working with minor bugs but I wrote it as a raw SQL query. Bugs are like, I get most voted articles with raw sql query, then use Eloquent's `whereIn` method with id's, but seems like it returns the response in a random order. Also, it would break Eloquent's `->isEmpty()` method which I'm using heavily in my views.

Long story short, I got sick of writing trying to write raw queries and solve numerous bugs (or side effects) on this little script. I want to carry it to Eloquent (with relationships) and be done with it.

My current database schema:

```
articles
--id

votes
--id
--user
--article_id
--vote
```

1. `Articles.id` and `votes.article_id` is related with `hasMany` (An article may have many votes)
2. `vote` column may contain `1` and `-1` values only.
3. I need to run a query that selects top 10 most positive voted articles. In raw sql, it is `group by votes.article_id order by sum(votes.vote)` (We don't select just positive votes, rather SUM of votes.vote column.)

For example:

```
articles.id
1
2

votes.id      votes.user       votes.article_id      votes_vote
1             User1            1                     1
2             User2            1                     1
3             User3            1                     -1 (this is negative vote)
4             User1            2                     1
5             User2            2                     1
```

Output should be:

```
Article 2 has (2) vote rating. // 1 + 1
Article 1 has (1) vote rating  // 1 + 1 - 1
```

How can I do this?

Ps. You can use Eloquent's `DB::raw` method if you want, as long as it uses Eloquent.

Comment: Could be a really better question if it was more concise!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

voila

```
Article::leftJoin(
    DB::raw('(SELECT article_id, SUM(vote) AS votes FROM votes GROUP BY post_id) as v'),
    'v.post_id', '=', 'posts.id'
)->orderBy('votes', 'desc')->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks alot. Take virtual hugs. <3